# IE 11 border-radius weirdness (did not occur in IE 9 and IE 10)

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-11

I have searched for similar questions related to border-radius in IE 11, but [only one found on the Microsoft IE Developer site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a7808c7d-0178-4b10-b8b1-fbb06dd6ee28/ie-11-div-with-borderradius-bug?forum=iewebdevelopment) described what I am also currently experiencing since "upgrading" to IE 11. The answer to the post in that thread was to make certain the DOCTYPE was HTML5, and not Quirks.

I am currently finishing a redesign on a website and yes, it's HTML5 and has the correct DOCTYPE, but I am still getting a weird problem with border-radius. There's a 1px offset to almost every element where I've applied a border-radius. If I uncheck border-radius, the problem disappears and all is fine, but shockingly this wasn't an issue in IE 9 or IE 10. Only since IE 11 a few days ago, has this problem surfaced. I have tested on both Windows 7 with IE 11 and Windows 8.1 with IE 11, and the problem exists on both.

Example 1:

[image]

I have a `border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px` here, and then apply separate pseudo elements :before and :after to get the pointed triangle, but the border-radius seems to be creating a 1px white line, so it's no longer flush with the rest of the element. This worked fine even in IE 8, but is now broken in IE 11. If I remove the border-radius, the pseudo element triangle becomes flush with the element again.

Example 2:

[image]

An `<a>` link button, displayed as inline-block has a linear-gradient for a background, a blue 1px solid border and `border-radius: 4px`. But the border-radius creates another 1px white line inside the blue 1px border. No matter any other border-radius value, the white line remains unless border-radius is 0.

Example 3:

[image]

Three `<a>` link elements set to `display: inline-block` inside a `<div>` positioned relative to another `<div>` below it. The bottom `<div>` has a `border-radius: 4px`, and the `<a>` elements inside the top `<div>` have border-radius on the top left and right (shown). IE 11 displays a 1px gap between the two `<div>` elements (like shown in the other posters thread linked above). But if the border-radius on the bottom `<div>` is set to 0, the gap disappears.

Again, none of these instances were an issue in IE 9 and IE 10; only since IE 11 has this "1px gap" with elements having border-radius appeared. I don't know how to fix it. Of course no other browsers are affected. Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome all display fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you have an image for example 3? If so, leave a comment with the URL and I will insert it into the question for you. You also mention someone else's thread, could you link that here as well?

Comment: Sure, here's an image for Example 3: http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y162/jrob007/ie11_radius2_zpsd64f5917.png and link to the Microsoft Dev site post is http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a7808c7d-0178-4b10-b8b1-fbb06dd6ee28/ie-11-div-with-borderradius-bug?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: What did you do to fix it?  Is this related to the appearance of white pixels on all rounded corners rendered on IE11?

Comment: It's clearly a bug in IE11, and was later confirmed by other users in that Microsoft IE Developer forum thread I linked in my post. The solution for now was to sub-pixel specify. In the case of Example 1, I had the triangle offset by `right:-19px;` which appeared fine in every browser except IE11 (shown above). The solution was to make it `right:-18.99999px;` and it seems to work in that case.

Comment: @jrob007 good workaround, worked for me (but I do left:99.9999% for triangle position). Please make an "answer" so people could notice it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's a bug with `border-radius` in IE11. The issue you describe may be part of the bigger picture. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018567/ie11-border-radius-and-border-bug).

Answer (score 0):

The fractional pixel workaround can cause Firefox to skew text over by 1 pixel, due to their pixel-aligned workaround for cleartype blurriness in selective font sizes.

The overflow:hidden wrapper workaround in [this msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a7808c7d-0178-4b10-b8b1-fbb06dd6ee28/ie-11-div-with-borderradius-bug) (where you posted) might be less prone to compatibility issues like that.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are forgot anchor tag reset property in your css.

Actually IE Automatically taken 1px Border, You Must write reset property in your css img tag, a tag border:none

Like Below Code

```
img {border:none;outline:none}
a {border:none;outline:none}
```