# Internet explorer 11 shows background when using border-radius

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

The IE 11 (11.0.9600.18350) seems to have some issues when using rounded borders. I made a minimal fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7phqrack/2/

html:

```
<div class="backgrounddiv">
  <div class="outer">
    <span id="span1">some content</span>
    <div class="inner">
      <span id="span2">more content in a nested div</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <span id="span1">some other content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

style:

```
.backgrounddiv{
  background: black;
}
.outer{
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  background: white;
}
.inner{
  background: white;

}
```

At some zoomlevels (130% on my machine) the background is visible between the two divs (and also at the upper border). Other browsers do not render the black line between the divs.

[image: screenshot from the fiddle made at 130% zoom]

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already asked:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018567/ie11-border-radius-and-border-bug)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051783/ie-11-border-radius-weirdness-did-not-occur-in-ie-9-and-ie-10)

It seems to be a bug in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this and see if it's remove the borders in Internet Explorer:

```
.outer{
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  background: white;
  border:0;
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: sadly, this does not work. In some cases this will help indeed, but not in all cases. By now I found a question on SO which explains this behavior as a bug.